# Walmart scraper gets blocked

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a walmart category from pages 1-100. I've implemented random headers and random wait times before requesting pages but still get hiy with a captcha after scraping the first few pages. Is walmart super good at detecing scrapers or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using selenium, bs4, and random_user_agent.

code:

```
# Randomize User Agents
software_names = [SoftwareName.CHROME.value]
operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value]

user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(
    software_names=software_names, operating_systems=operating_systems, limit=1000)

user_agents = user_agent_rotator.get_user_agents()

################################################

# Selenium
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
options.add_argument('use-fake-ui-for-media-stream')
options.add_argument(
    'load-extension=' + r'ad blocker path here')
options.add_argument("window-size=900,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
    "userAgent": user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()})
 driver.get(url)

 ################################################

# Randomize time between requests
time.sleep(randint(5, 15))
```

This is what I've tried to do so I don't get blocked. Are there better methods? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe increase the `time.sleep()`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks how to circumvent security measures of a commercial website.

Comment: There are many question on stack overflow asking how to not get blocked when scraping, I'm not trying to do anything malicoius so there's no reason to close my question

Comment: it might not be malicious, but there is clearly a reason they have put in such measures to prevent it. So why do you think your entitled to just ignore there wishes for there site to not be scrapped and just do it anyway?

Comment: scraping can be done for good reasons as well, there are lots of companies that scrape data in order to report fakes, stolen items, malicious sellers, etc. Walmart protects itself from malicious visits and attacks; scraping publicly accessible data is not a crime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IP is still the same for all the requests.
You could look into using python [requests with tor](https://medium.com/@jasonrigden/using-tor-with-the-python-request-library-79015b2606cb) which of course takes a bit longer though, because the request get's routed over TOR. I am not familiar with applying proxying over TOR with selenium but I bet there are a lot of tutorials you can find.

Walmart probably has this captcha mechanism in place for a reason though, so maybe look for another option of getting the data.

Comment: Looks promising, thank you